# Unable to write ssh file in boot partition on microSD using Windows for headless Raspberry Pi OS lite install

Tags: pi-zero, headless, image

This is my first time working with any Raspberry Pi. I'm trying to set up my pi zero for pi hole. Following an online guide, I downloaded Raspberry Pi OS Lite and used Raspberry Pi Imager to image the OS onto the microSD card.

This is where things start to diverge from the guides. After reinserting the microSD, File Explorer shows "USB Drive (K:)" and no other devices/drives (except "Local Disk (C:)"). In most guides this apparently should show up as "boot (K:)", I think. The fact that it is K is most likely due to me mucking around in disk management and reassigning the drive letter during some earlier attempts at troubleshooting.

Using Disk Management, I can see the drive labelled as "boot (K:)", and it has 2 partitions (256MB and 1.48GB, with 27.08GB unallocated)

In any case, "USB Drive (K:)" clearly contains the OS; there are many files including config.txt, kernel.img, etc.

**Here's my problem:** When I go to create an empty file titled "ssh" or "ssh.txt", I get the error:

> You can't save to 'K:'. Please choose another location.

I've tried with both VS Code and Notepad. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: how do you "go to create an empty file"? i.e. what do you do to create this empty file?

Comment: This is a problem with Windows - nothing to do with Pi.

Comment: 1) Open notepad 2) File->Save as 3) "ssh" as file name and "All Files (*.*)" as "Save as type" 4) Click save, get same error. Same thing happens if I change the extension to .txt.

Comment: I would start with a fresh image and use Etcher.  Make sure that the verify option is checked and when the image is done and Windows says it cannot read the disk IGNORE that.  It's OK to create a file called 'ssh.txt' - the Pi start up program looks for this or a file called 'ssh'

Comment: @Milliways was right - this was a problem with my hardware. On my windows computer, using my USB sd card reader didn't work. On my macbook, plugging the sd card directly into the built-in sd card reader didn't work. But using the same USB sd card reader in a USB port on my macbook magically worked. I confirmed this with a second sd card I borrowed from a friend. Thank you commenters for your help.